# Finding a dual Linear-Program

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

We are trying to prove Von-Neumann's MINIMAX Theorem namely

$$\max_{x\in\Delta_{n}}\min_{y\in\Delta_{m}}y^{T}Ax=\max_{x\in\Delta_{n}}\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}(Ax)_{i}$$

(Here $\Delta_k$ is the set of all probability distributions over $k$ elements)

We are stuck in the stage where we have to prove that the dual program of

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{maximize }t\\
s.t.:\\
 & \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_{i}\geqslant t\\
 & \sum x_{i}=1\\
 & \forall i,x_{i}\geqslant0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

is

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{minimize }w\\
s.t.:\\
 & \sum y_{j}^{T}a_{ij}\geqslant w\\
 & \sum y_{j}=1\\
 & \forall j,y_{j}\geqslant0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

How to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the original problem as
$$
\max \:t = \min \: -t\\
s.t.\quad Ax \succeq  t\mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1}^Tx = 1 \\
x \geq 0
$$

We can form the dual using Lagrange multipliers $w, y$, and $z$. We are now trying to minimize

$$L =  -t + y^T(t\mathbf{1}-Ax) + w(\mathbf{1}^Tx-1) - z^Tx\\
 = t(-1 -y^T\mathbf{1}) +(-y^TA+w\mathbf{1}^T-z^T)x - w
$$
over all $x,t$. We see that the terms corresponding to the primal variables can grow unbounded unless the coefficients in the dual variables are zero.  Thus, the dual problem is

$$
\max \:-w = \min w\\
s.t. \quad -A^Ty + w\mathbf{1} = z \\
y^T\mathbf{1} = 1\\
z,y \succeq 0
$$

We can eliminate $z$ by rewriting: 
$$
\min \:w\\
s.t. \quad -A^Ty + w\mathbf{1} \succeq 0 \implies A^Ty \preceq w\mathbf{1}\\
y^T\mathbf{1} = 1\\
y \succeq 0
$$